# function pointer array: void** cast

Tags: c, arrays, void

i am rather new to c and c++. I have the task (it is more for practise) to change a given c-module into c++. For this purpose, i have to understand the c files first.

I have two specific questions, but i would like to outline parts of the function shortly. I try to use general identifiers.

**Excerpts of c code:**

There is a Broker which provides functions to register callbacks. The Broker holds the different types of callbacks in respective arrays.

First, they declared a couple of function pointers to specify the callback:

```
typedef bool (*ReadRequestCallback_tpf)  (param1 a, param2 b, param3 c);
typedef bool (*ReadResponseCallback_tpf) (param4 a, param5 b);
typedef bool (*WriteRequestCallback_tpf) (param6 a, param7 b, param8 c);
...
```

Then, they made arrays for each type to hold registered callbacks:

```
ReadRequestCallback_tpf  ReadRequest_apf  [MaxReadRequest];
ReadResponseCallback_tpf ReadResponse_apf [MaxReadResponse];
WriteRequestCallback_tpf WriteRequest_apf [MaxWriteRequest];
```

There are functions given to register new callback:

```
void RegisterReadRequestCallback_v (ReadRequestCallback_tpf callback_pf){
    AddCallback_v((void**)ReadRequest_apf, (void*) callback_pf);
}
void RegisterReadResponseCallback_v (ReadResponseCallback_tpf callback_pf){
    AddCallback_v((void**)ReadResponse_apf, (void*) callback_pf);
}
void RegisterWriteRequestCallback_v (WriteRequestCallback_tpf callback_pf){
    AddCallback_v((void**)WriteRequest_apf, (void*) callback_pf);
}
```

The signature of `AddCallback_v` is like:

```
void AddCallback_v (void* Array_apv[], void* function_pf)
```

**My questions:**

1. is `(void**) array_apf` really `void* array_apv`? 
   So the cast of an 'array of function pointers' to 'void-pointer to void-pointer' equals a 'void-pointer to an array of void-pointer'?
   Since it works, it seems so. But i dont really understand it.
2. When trying to change it (or parts) to c++, is it a better way to use a template instead the cast to (void*)?

This is my first entry here. I hope, i could explain my questions. If something needs to be clearified, please let me know.

Kind regards and thank you in advance

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language, which one are you actually using?

Comment: The actual code is written in C. Every code excerpt is in C. In future, it should be written in C++.

Comment: instead of the array you can try a vector of std::function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C code is actually broken. Whereas *any pointer to any object* can be *converted* to a *pointer to void*, this isn't true for *pointers to functions*. Furthermore, there is no guarantee that a pointer to a function can be *reinterpreted* as a *pointer-to-void* in C. That means that the function

```
void RegisterReadRequestCallback_v (ReadRequestCallback_tpf callback_pf){
    AddCallback_v((void**)ReadRequest_apf, (void*) callback_pf);
}
```

is broken in many ways, including that it breaks strict aliasing. It is just so wrong that it hurts.

The intent of that apparently is that there is a generic function named `AddCallback_v` that gets a pointer to the callback array, and a new callback function, however C doesn't guarantee that that would work like that!

In C, the proper way to code this would be to have `Readrequest_apf` etc be arrays of generic *pointers-to-functions*; that would be cast back to `ReadRequestCallback_tpf` et al prior to calling them, i.e.

```
typedef bool (*GenericCallback_tpf)();

GenericCallback_tpf ReadRequest_apf[MaxReadRequest];

void AddCallback_v(GenericCallback_tpf callback_array[]);

void RegisterReadRequestCallback_v (ReadRequestCallback_tpf callback_pf){
    AddCallback_v(ReadRequest_apf, (GenericCallback_tpf)callback_pf);
}
```

And upon calling:

```
((ReadRequestCallback_tpf)ReadRequest_apf[i])(param1, param2, param3);
```

---

In C++ you'd use a *vector of functors* for each of these `*_apf`; and therefore would not need to have casts.

Answer (score 1):

1. When an array is passed to a function, it's automatically converted to a pointer to the first element. So in a function declaration, `TYPE array[]` is equivalent to `TYPE *array`. Therefore, `void *array[]` is equivalent to `void **array`.
2. One of the purposes of templates is to avoid having to use a `void *` type for generic functions, as there's no way for the compiler to ensure that you're casting it back to the original type when the pointer is used. So yes, templates are often a better solution than functions that take `void*` parameters.